# In Log4js how do you enable tracing?

Tags: node.js, log4js-node

In the documentation I could find for Log4js, there is a function `isTraceEnabled()`, which is defined as

> isTraceEnabled
>
> checks if Level Trace is enabled

However, I can't find anywhere how do you actually enable (not check) this trace level. How can you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `is<level>Enabled()` - returns true if a log event of level (camel case) would be dispatched to the appender defined for the logger's category. For example: `logger.isInfoEnabled()` will return true if the level for the logger is INFO or lower.

Like the documentation sais, `is<level>Enabled()` returns true if a log event of that level is enabled.

There are all this levels:

> ALL < TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < MARK < OFF

Left ones includes the others on the right side.

To set the level of the logger set the `level` property to the desired one. For example:

```
var logger = log4js.getLogger();
logger.level = 'debug';
```

In this concrete case `isTraceEnabled()` will return `false`. If you use either `trace` or `all` it will return `true`.